# Combining checkbox selectors for unique results in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have 3 checkboxes, and I want all combinations of those checkboxes to display a different result, but I cannot work out how to do so. It feels like there's a simple way of doing this that I'm missing.

Here's the Frankenstein monster-code I have so far, which doesn't do what I'd like it to. The aim is that the following code sees that a user has has checked both the "webcam" (#checkWebcam) and "chat" (#checkChat) boxes, and that a different download link is being displayed based on that selection combo...

```
jQuery('#checkWebcam, #checkChat').change(function() {
    var isChecked = jQuery('#checkWebcam, #checkChat').is(':checked');
    if(isChecked)
        jQuery('div.strip.download').html('<a href="<?php echo $nos; ?>" class="btn btn-lg btn-to gradient-to">Download</a>');
    else
        jQuery('div.strip.download').html('<a href="<?php echo $download; ?>" class="btn btn-lg btn-to gradient-to">Download</a>');
});
```

Could anyone help me with how to actually achieve this aim? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This will do an `OR` operation,

```
var isChecked = jQuery('#checkWebcam, #checkChat').is(':checked');
```

what you basically need is to perform an `AND` opereation here, so use

```
var isChecked = jQuery('#checkWebcam').is(':checked') && $('#checkChat').is(':checked');
```

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Wont it return true if any one of the selector matches the requirement..? let me test that in a fiddle..

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi But i tested it here.. http://jsfiddle.net/NW5dX/ Please explain..

Comment: Well, I should have done the same, because I'm indeed completely wrong. I was under the impression `is()` behaved the same as a getter, but the documentation agrees with you. My apologies.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi i remember, once adneo told about this to me.. And it is so kind of you... :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. && operators are something I'm familiar with, and didn't know they worked in jQuery. I've tried to do as you've suggested, but I can't seem to get it working. Would you be able to put an example of how to use it into a jsFiddle? Would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code :

```
if ( $("#checkWebcam:checked, #checkChat:checked").length == 2 ) {
    //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`var isChecked = jQuery('#checkWebcam, #checkChat').is(':checked');` will return `true` if either one or both are selected.

Modify your code as

```
jQuery('#checkWebcam, #checkChat').change(function() {
    var boxs = jQuery('#checkWebcam, #checkChat');
    var checked = boxs.filter(':checked'); //Filter checked checkboxes
    if(boxs.length == checked.length){ //if length are same
        alert('both are checked')
    }else{
        alert('both are not checked')
    }    
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2GR3/)

Comment: I think I understand how your solution works, but the idea is that users can tick/untick a choice of 3 checkboxes, ultimately creating maybe 8 or 9 combinations of results. This looks as if it could only support a binary kind of yes/no situation.  Is that correct, or am I misreading?